# pip3 command fails after upgrading to pip version 18.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

After upgrading pip3 using `$ pip3 install --upgrade pip`, pip3 fails to work.  And throws this:
Error Command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
        from pip import main
    ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

it's having the same issue again even after removing the pip3 and reinstalling it.

Somewhere someone suggested to change the `from pip import main` to `from pip._internal import main`. But still it didn't work.

Comment: This should probably be on superuser, but are you on Ubuntu? Sometimes their pip command interferes, so try uninstalling the version of pip that is supplied by your OS' package manager

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it's best to leave your OS's Python installation alone, as it can be used for system dependencies. Install a clean version of Python with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), and/or use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)/[Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for development.

The pip3 command in the stack trace is in the system's binary path, and thus was probably installed by your operating system's package manager. It will be expecting an older version of pip, which you've removed by upgrading it.

As a temporary workaround, try running `/usr/local/bin/pip3`.